# sf::RenderWindow renders nothing

Tags: c++11, sfml

What I am essentially trying to do is to rewrite [this lesson](https://github.com/SFML/SFML-Game-Development-Book/tree/master/04_Input), put the code into different folders and add Box2D support. Everything was fine before I've created `EWorld` and `EGame` classes. Now `RenderWindow` renders nothing, though `clear` method is called.

My code [lives here](https://github.com/montreal91/workshop/tree/master/jumble/box_and_hits) and I have no idea what am I doing wrong with `RenderWindow` object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`clear` empties the screen to show nothing.

To have things properly render on each frame you need to follow this pattern:

```
window.clear(); // clear drawn objects from previous frame
// window.draw(...); all the things for this frame
window.display(); // actually show drawn frame on screen
```